# Installing gem compass error (Failed to open connection to localhost:80 in Windows)

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, compass

How can I get rid of this one... Thanks

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:

Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/

- Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:80

  (No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
- connect(2) for "localhost" port 80) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: try with this gem install compass

Comment: I try that, but the same error

Comment: Strange it's trying to connect to `localhost:80` for Ruby Gems. What happens if you run: `gem install compass --source https://rubygems.org`